Meaning of "while it was not clear whether it was a case of pouring passion onto his reason"
Here is the text:

Fortunately Koroku had not descended on them again. A young man of a
compulsive and excitable temperament, he would pursue unremittingly
whatever was uppermost in his mind, a trait that had been apparent in
the Sōsuke of distant schooldays. On the other hand, when Koroku’s
mood changed he became a different person, with a good-natured look on
his face, as if the cares of yesterday were totally forgotten. Here
too the brothers’ common blood showed: Sōsuke had been just like this
long ago. Koroku had a relatively lucid mind and, while it was not
clear whether it was a case of pouring passion onto his reason or
cloaking his emotions in rational trappings, he was at any rate never
satisfied with a proposition until he could discern its underlying
logic; once he had done so, he would zealously push it to its
conclusion. His will, moreover, was far stronger than his physical
constitution might suggest, and his youthful impetuosity made him
capable of almost anything.

Does it mean: when he was going to decide about something and it was not clear to him whether it was the case to act emotionally or logically he never decide until he find a logical answer and he did that?
I do not get the meaning of "pouring passion onto his reason" and "its underlying logic". and the whole phrase is unclear to me.
Source: The Gate by NATSUME SŌSEKI Translated by WILLIAM F. SIBLEY

pour passion on reason: in other words, reason disappears and passion remains. Look up: the trappings of something. to cloak [cover] emotions in what appears to be [trappings]  rational, The rest is pretty simple.

My reading focuses on the author’s offering of a pair of alternatives: Which of reason and emotion is at the core of Koroku’s attitude, and which is only a surface feature? For me, the passage’s meaning is that making that choice would be difficult.

Not to interpret the metaphors, merely pointing them out...
To "pour passion onto" something casts passion as a liquid of some kind. Gasoline? Water? Hot cocoa? Tea?
The "underlying logic of a proposition" casts the logic as something that is not on the "surface" of the proposition, but something that is below it, its basis or foundation. A spatial metaphor or a construction metaphor.
Reason is usually depicted as cold and calculating, passion as hot and wild.  But here there is some sort of mitigation or moderation happening, when passion and reason are mixed.  The passion is being poured onto reason (an incendiary liquid? or the opposite, a quenching?) or passion is being dressed in the garb of reason (a disguise? a costume? a uniform?)  So you have a liquid metaphor and a clothing metaphor at play in that sentence. You're on your own figuring out what it means.

I do not get the meaning of the whole part in bold and the meaning of "pouring passion onto his reason"" clearly. Could you write the whole part in bold in other words?

Sorry, interpretation is off-topic on this language-learning forum. I have pointed out that the language is figurative, but it is up to you to interpret it.

@ViserHashemi If you want help with interpretation, so can post the question on Literature Stack Exchange.
